# Array assignment erases previous values on array

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm running the following code, that is the implementation of a Runge-Kutta method to solve a system of differential equations.
The main code just calls the `rk` subroutine, which is the implementation itself, and `myfun` is just an example to test the code.

```
program main

    use ivp_odes

    implicit none

    double precision, allocatable :: t(:), y(:,:)
    double precision :: t0, tf, y0(2), h
    integer :: i

    t0 = 0d0
    tf = 0.5d0
    y0 = [0d0, 0d0]
    h = 0.1d0

    call rk4(t, y, myfun, t0, tf, y0, h)

    do i=0,size(t)
        print *, t(i), y(:,i)
    end do

contains

pure function myfun(t,y) result(dy)
    ! input variables
    double precision, intent(in) :: t, y(:)

    ! output variables
    double precision :: dy(size(y))

    dy(1) = -4*y(1) + 3*y(2) + 6
    dy(2) = -2.4*y(1) + 1.6*y(2) + 3.6
end function myfun

end program main
```

and the subroutine is inside a module:

```
module ivp_odes
    implicit none

contains

subroutine rk4(t, y, f, t0, tf, y0, h)
    ! input variables
    double precision, intent(in) :: t0, tf, y0(1:)
    double precision, intent(in) :: h

    interface
        pure function f(t,y0) result(dy)
            double precision, intent(in) :: t, y0(:)
            double precision :: dy(size(y))
        end function
    end interface

    ! output variables
    double precision, allocatable :: t(:), y(:,:)

    ! Variáveis auxiliares
    integer :: i, m, NN
    double precision, allocatable :: k1(:), k2(:), k3(:), k4(:)

    m = size(y0)
    allocate(k1(m),k2(m),k3(m),k4(m))

    NN = ceiling((tf-t0)/h)
    if (.not. allocated(y)) then
        allocate(y(m,0:NN))
    else
        deallocate(y)
        allocate(y(m,0:NN))
    end if

    if (.not. allocated(t)) then
        allocate(t(0:NN))
    else
        deallocate(t)
        allocate(t(0:NN))
    end if

    t(0) = t0
    y(:,0) = y0


    do i=1,NN
        k1(:) = h * f(t(i-1)     , y(:,i-1)        )
        k2(:) = h * f(t(i-1)+h/2 , y(:,i-1)+k1(:)/2)
        k3(:) = h * f(t(i-1)+h/2 , y(:,i-1)+k2(:)/2)
        k4(:) = h * f(t(i-1)+h   , y(:,i-1)+k3(:)  )

        y(:,i) = y(:,i-1) + (k1(:) + 2*k2(:) + 2*k3(:) + k4(:))/6
        t(i) = t(i-1) + h
    end do

    deallocate(k1,k2,k3,k4)
    return

end subroutine rk4

end module ivp_odes
```

The problem here is that the assignment in the `rk` subroutine

```
y(:,i) = y(:,i-1) + (k1(:) + 2*k2(:) + 2*k3(:) + k4(:))/6
```

is erasing the previous values calculated. In the i-th iteration of the do-loop, it erases the previous values of the array `y` and assigns just the i-th column of the array `y`, so when the subroutine ends, `y` has only the last value saved.
Since Fortran has implemented element-wise operations and assignments to arrays, I think the code this is easier to read and probably runs faster than doing assignments to each element in a loop. So, why is it not working? What am I missing in the assignment here? Shouldn't it just change the values in the i-th row, instead of also erasing the rest of the array?

Comment: How are you ascertaining that every column in `y` except for the last has been erased?  Are you sure that you passed in a 2D array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical case of accessing an array out of its bounds. You can find these errors easily using the appropriate compiler flags. With `gfortran`, this would be `-fbounds-check`.

With such checks you will find the error to be an erroneous size of the function result in the interface block - `dy` should have the same length as `y0` (the one-dimensional dummy argument of `f`), and not `y`:

```
    interface
        pure function f(t,y0) result(dy)
            double precision, intent(in) :: t, y0(:)
            double precision :: dy(size(y0))
        end function
    end interface
```

Additionally, although not related to your particular error, you started indexing of `t` and the second dimension of `y` with zero. So you need to adjust the loop in the main program run to `size(t)-1` only, or use `ubound(t)`. Otherwise you will, again, exceed the boundaries of the arrays.